# Install a DOS application consisting of 5 .IMG files (when expanded) on Windows 10 running DOSBox-X

Tags: floppy-disk, disk-image, dosbox

I downloaded a copy of [DataEase 4.5](https://winworldpc.com/product/dataease/45) database.  Once I expanded the download, it had five `.IMG` files representing the original five 3.5" floppy disks.

I wish to install the software so it can run with DOSBox-X on my Windows 10 laptop. How would I go about doing the installation?

I have extracted and stored all the `.IMG` files in one directory and tried the install but it didn't succeed.

Comment: Voting to reopen as it's about using -old software-.

Comment: @knol Not really, as the question does not ask anything about the old software, but explicit about how to operate a modern simulator.

Answer (score 14):

The following DOSBox command:

```
imgmount a 1.img 2.img 3.img 4.img 5.img -t floppy
```

loads five floppy images for use as the emulated A: drive. If the disk images are not in the current working directory when DOSBox is started, you may have to specify their relative or full absolute paths. It's easier to prepare that command in a batch file (using Notepad) in your host OS and then run the batch file in your DOSBox, instead of typing out long pathnames in the DOSBox shell.

One disk is inserted at a time, starting with the first. While mounted in this manner <kbd>Ctrl-F4</kbd> cycles the currently inserted disk through the list.

Use these commands to insert disk 1, then follow the standard installation procedure for your software, swapping disks when prompted.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of `CTRL-F4` but are you sure it actually works? I can't get it to swap disks and I'm not sure how it would know to do so given that there may be *multiple* sequences mounted (drive `A` and `B` for example). UPDATE: Actually, looking at the doco, `CTRL-F4` seems to be tied to ISO *optical* disk images rather than floppies. That may explain why it's not working.

Comment: Hmm, I'm hoping this isn't one of the (relatively) more recent features that's only present on certain point versions or svn. It's certainly the -intended- interface for mounting a sequence of imgs.

Comment: Regarding the batch file: If those files are the only IMG files in the folder `imgmount a *.img` is enough.  The `-t floppy` is implied by the drive letter `a`.

Comment: The asterisk is less convenient if the disks have odd names (Install, Data1, Data2, Tools) etc and you want control over the insertion order :) I've learned to always specify the type since dosbox will sometimes complain about (seemingly) obvious CD images.

Comment: knol, I'm pretty certain it *is* available, I'm using the most recent but one release and it's in the doco. It may just be for ISOs only though, based on what the doco says. Even then, I can't see how it would work if there are *multiple* sequences mounted (say a sequence each on two *different* CD readers) unless maybe it pops up a dialog box to ask in that case ??

Comment: Keep in mind everything else in your answer works (specifically `imgmount`). I just couldn't get the `CTRL-F4` working, so had to revert to `imgswap` to do the actual swapping. I'm not sure that's viable for an install however since it requires the CLI and you're wanting to do it in the middle of running a program. The menu-based method would be fine though.

Comment: The issue here presumably is that both the OP and @paxdiablo are using DOSBox-X, which [changes most shortcuts](https://dosbox-x.com/wiki/Home.html#_dosbox_xs_special_keys) from what they are in plain DOSBox. F11 + O (on Windows) or F12 + O (elsewhere) should work for swapping floppies.

Answer (score 12):

At least in DOSBox-X version `2022.09.0`<sup>(1)</sup>, you can mount a sequence of disk images to drive `A:` simply by mounting from the drive menu:

[image]

You should *probably* first select the `Option: Mount images read-only` option so as not to allow changes to the image files.

If you load a sequence of images, you use `Swap disk` to cycle through the drives one by one, then finally `Unmount drive` to unmount the entire sequence when you're done.

This *can* also be done using the CLI tools `imgmount` and `imgswap`, but I prefer the menu-based method myself. However, should you prefer the CLI tools, you can run them with the `/?` flag to describe how to use them. Just keep in mind you're unlikely to be able to run CLI tools if you're in the middle of installing an application in DOS (the installer will be in control rather than `command.com`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> This is the version I'm currently running, having not yet upgraded to the latest (at time of answer) `2022.12.26`, That's  due to the fact that the Windows installers were not actually built for that release.